# How to find duplicates in a csv column, and remove any row that doesn't have a duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv with data that looks like this:

```
777 Brockton Avenue,Abington,MA,2351
30 Memorial Drive,Avon,MA,2322
250 Hartford Avenue,Bellingham,MA,2351
700 Oak Street,Brockton,MA,2301
66-4 Parkhurst Rd,Chelmsford,MA,1824
591 Memorial Dr,Chicopee,MA,2351
55 Brooksby Village Way,Danvers,MA,2301
```

I want to search the last column (the one with the zipcodes), find any duplicates and remove any row that **doesn't** have a duplicate in that row.

So the data above would turn into:

```
777 Brockton Avenue,Abington,MA,2351
250 Hartford Avenue,Bellingham,MA,2351
700 Oak Street,Brockton,MA,2301
591 Memorial Dr,Chicopee,MA,2351
55 Brooksby Village Way,Danvers,MA,2301
```

I have tried using Pandas and a lot of other methods but I am still having a lot of trouble doing this. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: BTW, if you like shell you may try this command: egrep $(rev test.csv | sort |cut -d',' -f1 | uniq -d| rev |tr  "\n" "|"  |sed -e 's/|$//g') test.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to index rows by zip code. `collections.defaultdict` is nice because you don't specifically have to create a list whenever a new zip code is found. The defaultdict will use the initializer you give it (in this case the `list` class) in that case.

Once you have populated the dict, its values are lists grouped by zip code and any list > 1 meets your criteria.

```
import csv
import collections

zip_index = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('test.csv', newline='') as fileobj:
    reader = csv.reader(fileobj)
    for row in reader:
        zip_index[row[-1]].append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fileobj:
    writer = csv.writer(fileobj)
    for rows in zip_index.values():
        if len(rows) > 1:
            writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have it as a textfile, as in the original post, you could just split each line and use the last element. Use a dictionary to keep track of the number of repetitions of each zip code and then loop a second time through all lines, only keeping the ones that have a zip code which occurs more than once:

```
lines = ["777 Brockton Avenue,Abington,MA,2351",
         "30 Memorial Drive,Avon,MA,2322",
         "250 Hartford Avenue,Bellingham,MA,2351",
         "700 Oak Street,Brockton,MA,2301",
         "66-4 Parkhurst Rd,Chelmsford,MA,1824",
         "591 Memorial Dr,Chicopee,MA,2351",
         "55 Brooksby Village Way,Danvers,MA,2301"]

## Get an overview of duplicates
zipdir = {}
for l in lines:
    try:
        zipdir[l.split(",")[-1]] +=1
    except:
        zipdir[l.split(",")[-1]] = 1

## Retain the ones with more than one occurrence
outlines = []
for l in lines:
    if zipdir[l.split(",")[-1]]>1:
        outlines.append(l)
```

In your case, this would remove two elements from the data. A list of lines may be obtained from a csv by just opening it as a file (`infile = open("xy.csv","r")`) and reading all lines as a list (`lines = infile.readlines()`). Similarily, the resulting list of lines may be written by just writing them as a joined string with a line feed delimiter (`outfile.write("\n".join(outlines)`).

No packages are required for such a task.